# Executing code after AngularJS template is rendered

Tags: angularjs

I have a table that renders rows with `ng-repeat`. Inside one of the cells there is a select that is rendered with `ng-options`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data.items" repeat-done>
 <td >
  ...
  <select class="selectpicker" 
        ng-model="person" ng-options="person.Surname for person in data.Persons track by person.Id">
   <option value="">Introduce yourself...</option>
  </select>
  ...
 <td>
</tr>
```

When repeat is done I need to turn select into bootstrap-select (a nice looking dropdownlist). So after a little bit of researching I added the following directive:

```
app.directive('repeatDone', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            setTimeout(function() { $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); }, 1);
        };
    };
});
```

which is specified at tr (see above).

It works. But I am a little bit worried whether there is a chance it will not work on slow PC/tablet/etc. As I understand AngularJS has an asynchronous nature. So while the last element of `ng-repeat` is being processed, it is still possible `ng-options` for this element (or may be for some previous element too) is not rendered. Or am I paranoiac?

Comment: There is a directive wrapper available [here](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select) that may help.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn´t synchronize your directives using timeout. A lot of problems can appear.

You can use the option *priority* to sort when your directives are going to be used. Directives are executed on descendant order.

ngRepeat has priority 1000 (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)
select has priority 0 (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

If you declare your directive with a negative priority it will execute after ng-options.

```
app.directive('repeatDone', function () {
    return {
        priority: -5,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); 
        }
    }
});
```

According to Angular documentation:

> priority
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Why it didn't work? Was it executed before ng-options?